# How to build against the RestKit framework in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x) for integrating RestKit into my project but I am running into some problems. When I add a target dependencies the dialog that popup does not have the bulls eye. I still select the RestKit one (this has a little building next to that's white. Then when I click on Link with Libraries, and I dont get the choices to add the libraries for restkit. Ive tried this in my current project, a blank project, and nothing seems to work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That tutorial is a little out of date. They updated the way Restkit builds (simplified it). There's a thread about it on the Restkit mailing list.

That said, here's what it would look like with the latest Xcode: [image: add-items-screenshot]

So for iOS you'd select the first on the list, with the little house-looking graphic. For Mac you'd choose the framework.

Answer (score 2):

I found the tutorial at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x to work with Xcode4.2. Make sure you follow all the directions. But, here's the catch. I couldn't get it to work with a project that I convert from xcode3. Probably could have but gave up. I made a new project in 4, dropped all my sources in it, then followed the directions in the above tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag the libRestKit.a file from the Products Group of the RestKit project into the Link with Libraries Build Phase of the build target that needs it.

Comment: libRestKit.a is not one of the files I need, according the tutorial I need: libRestKitNetwork.a, libRestKitObjectMapping.a, libRestKitSupport.a, libRestKitJSONParserJSONKit, libRestKitXMLParserLibxml.a When I open products LibRestKit.a is red. I have tried downloading the zip file and using git to clone and both get the same results.

Comment: The product will be red if it hasn't been built yet. You should still be able to add it to the build phase and it'll be built when it's needed. Perhaps the RestKit developers have rolled all the .a files into one? Have you tried building against this library?

Comment: @joerick - Thank you for the red tip.  That has saved my butt!